# Statusbar color in cordova

Tags: android, css, cordova

I have a webapp that I created with Polymer and packaged it with Cordova. On a mobile web browser I can just add a `theme-color` meta property to change the URL bar and status bar color, how can I recreate that with Cordova?
For example:

[image: Gray bar with app name and icon]

[image: Black status bar]

How can I change the color of the gray (action?)bar and the black status bar?

Comment: search for (cordova status bar plugin) and (cordova action bar plugin). There are a few to check

Comment: @Tasos I was hoping if there was more programmatic approach rather than adding another plugin.

Comment: Im not sure, but maybe the plugins will work for Pre Kitkat too, That will  be the good thing about them.